# How to glue last column to the right side of the ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, treeview, scrollbar

[image]

I have one TreeView and one ListView on top of it. The idea is the two components to work together and form one horizontal tree view with column headers above each tree level.

I would like to either hide the horizontal scroll and prevent the column headers to exit the viewable area or to synchronize the horizontal scrollbar of the TreeView and the ListView. I don't know how to implement either. Any ideas?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Name="listView" Width="{Binding ElementName=sampleTree, Path=Width}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="gridView" AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Subject" x:Name="col1" Width="105"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Module" x:Name="col2"  Width="105"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Component" x:Name="col3" Width="105"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Task" x:Name="col4" Width="105"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="State" x:Name="col5" Width="105"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <TreeView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="sampleTree" ItemsSource="{Binding AssessmentFramework}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:TreeNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="3" Margin="1">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=Id, Converter={StaticResource TextBoxEnableConverter}}" FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent">
                        <TextBox.Width>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey = ColumnToTreeNodeWidthConverter}">
                                <Binding ElementName="col1" Path="Width"/>
                                <Binding ElementName="col2" Path="Width"/>
                                <Binding ElementName="col3" Path="Width"/>
                                <Binding ElementName="col4" Path="Width"/>
                                <Binding ElementName="col5" Path="Width"/>
                                <Binding Path="Lvl"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBox.Width>
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <behaviors:TextBoxDoubleClickBehavior/>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </TextBox>
                </Border>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: After looking at your image, I still can't figure out what you're asking for... could you elaborate?

Comment: Sure. Basically I am using only the headers of the ListView. When a user resize the column header, the width of the tree elements in the corresponding lvl resize too. The problem is that by default the user can resize the columns so that they hide from the viewable area. You can see in the picture that half of the last column header is hidden. I want to prevent the header columns from going out of view. Or to synchronise the tree view horizontal scroller with the ListView headers, so that when the scroller moves the viewable area of the ListView headers moves too.

Comment: Can you not just either change the width of the `Grid` to accommodate for the new width or just wrap both the `ListView` and `TreeView` in a `ScrollViewer`?

Comment: That is a good idea. I'll try it out. Thanks.